# Reversing a Queue in python using list

Tags: python, list, recursion, queue

[image]

I used recursion in python to reverse queue in python .
in rev method it has 3 methods to call for every recursion 1.pop,2.rev and 3.append
but method append not invoking every recursion it invoking only after all rev recursions completed.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. It's not searchable or accessible to people who use screen readers and nobody wants to retype your code to prove a good answer. Take the time to paste it into the question and format it.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216119/how-do-i-reverse-a-list-using-recursion-in-python